# Google Apps Script textfinder returns null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use a textfinder to select a certain cell in a range. The textfinder returns null, despite the text that it's looking for is in the specified range. Anyone got a hand?

Cell E4 in sh1 (named: Check) is the variable that needs to be searched for in another range, because of this I am using var "trailer".

Range X4:X48 in sh2 (named: Lodge) has the value from E4 somewhere in that range, I am trying to select that specific cell.

The text in E4 changes based on criteria, that is why it needs to be variable instead of a set string.

Logger.log(trailer) returns the value of E4
Logger.log(test) returns null

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Check");
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Lodge");
  var range = sh1.getRange("E4");
  var trailer = range.getValue();


    Logger.log(trailer);

    var test = sh2.getRange("X4:X48").createTextFinder(trailer).matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(false).matchFormulaText(true).getCurrentMatch();

    Logger.log(test);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sh1.getRange("A1");
  var trailer = range.getValue();
  var test = sh2.getRange("A1:X48").createTextFinder(trailer).matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(false).findAll(); 
  test.forEach(rg => {
    Logger.log('range: %s, value: %s',rg.getA1Notation(),rg.getValue());
  })
}
```